# Missing Firmware

Tags: release-hera, updates

I am brand new to eOS. I downloaded and installed then updated eOS Hera 5.1.6. After my final update this morning I get this message:

"Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915"

I ran sudo update-initramfs -u but the problem still exists - I get the same message. As a new user, is there anything else I can try?

Is there a PPA I should add to resolve this? Is the solution on synaptic?

Thank you in advance from a newb

Comment: Welcome to elementary!. Please update your question with your CPU information. The issue is caused by the i915 driver which controls the integrated graphic card. Executing `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall ` or updating the kernel manually will probably solve it.

Answer (score 3):

### Resolve Missing Firmware Warnings

*If everything is working fine, then those warnings are of no importance so technically you can ignore them. Anyway, to have a peace of mind you can get rid of those by manually downloading and installing firmwares.*

First download all missing firmwares from Intel repository of firmware blobs:

For **i915**: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/i915

For **rtl_nic**: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/rtl_nic/

Then copy all to corresponding lib firmware folders

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/*.bin /lib/firmware/i915/
sudo cp ~/Downloads/*.fw /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/
```

Lastly update initramfs

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

And now you can sleep well at night